# Filemaker Pro 15 Advanced - manage newsletter sending to contacts

Tags: filemaker

I'm pretty new to Filemaker and I'm trying to build a email subscription list management system with it. I have a table with my contacts, another table with existing newsletter publications (pdf) and would like to build a view that gives me for each contact the status of their received publications (which I will send directly from Filemaker).
I'm targeting something like that:

```
Contact 1   
---------
Newsletter 1       SENT 01/12/2016
Neswletter 2       SENT 01/01/2017
Newsletter 3       (Send now)
Newsletter 3       (Send now)
```

I had done a table which would store the already sent messages (contact ID and newsletter ID pairs with a timestamp) which allowed me to list the already sent newsletters for each contact, but I have no idea on which approach to take in order to retrieve and list the ones that have not been sent yet.

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: What exactly do your contacts subscribe to? A newsletter with several issues, or to specific issues?

Comment: @michael.hor257k - they would subscribe to the newsletter and receive all issues. But as new subscribers arrive over time, we'd like to have the possibility to send them issues that were published before they joined.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there is only one newsletter (with multiple issues), you will need 3 tables: Subscribers, Issues and Mailings - where Mailings is a *join table* between the other two, with fields for:

- **SubscriberID** (link to Subscribers);
- **IssueID** (link to Issues);
- **MailingDate**

A portal to Mailings, placed on a layout of Subscribers, will show all the issues that have been mailed to the currently viewed subscriber.

There are numerous options to view the unmailed issues - I will mention two:

1. Have a script go to related records from Issues (show only related records), then show only omitted.
2. Define another relationship between Subscribers and (a new occurrence of) Issues, using the `x` relational operator. Place a portal to this TO of Issues on a layout of Subscribers, and use conditional formatting to distinguish between mailed and unmailed issues.

Comment: Re option 1 - sounds interesting but I've never played with scripts before (in FM at least), no clue where I would even start :/ . Re option 2 - tried to do that (2nd) portal it gives me a second list with all the issues in it. I'm confused anyway because I don't understand why (and how) I'd make a direct relationship between  subscribers and issuers. Shouldn't the connection be between issues and mailings ?

Comment: @Argoron I highly recommend you join one of the forums dedicated to the FileMaker platform, where these issues can be discussed at length.

Comment: @Argoron Basic scripting is very easy with FileMaker. I would suggest (in addition to joining a FileMaker-specific forum such as fmforums.com) that you just think of what you would manually do to perform the task. FileMaker scripts, at their simplest are just reproductions of steps that can be manually taken, so if you are able to manually perform the task, translating that to a script should be fairly straightforward. Check the FileMaker documentation for the available script steps.